# Information on forwarding queue occupation (if existent)

Tags: linux, forwarding

I have a router forwarding traffic from a network to another and I need to know when the packet queue (in the receiving side/interface - rx) occupation is close to its maximum capacity.

However, after analysing the following files:

- **tcp_mem/tcp_rmem/tcp_wmem** in /proc/sys/net/ipv4
- **tx_queue_len** in /sys/class/net/(interface)
- **sockstat** in /proc/net

I concluded these files would only be relevant for my problem if the router was the destination or source of the TCP packets. So, as I discussed with a professor, these metrics are not relevant in a forwarding situation, as the packets do not go to the TCP queues.

If that's true, then where can I find information on forwarding queue's current occupation and its maximum occupation, if there's any information on the matter?